# Edit and Delete Action composite primary keys issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This my Edit Controller :

```
public ActionResult Edit(short id)
{
    TAUX taux = db.TAUX.Find(id);
    if (taux == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.CAT_ID = new SelectList(db.CATEGORIE, "CAT_ID", "LIBELLE", taux.CAT_ID);
    ViewBag.C_GARANT = new SelectList(db.GARANTIE, "C_GARANT", "LIB_ABREGE", taux.C_GARANT);
    return PartialView("_Edit",taux);
}
```

And this is how I call it in my view :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", new {  id=d.TAUX_ID })
```

This my model `Taux` :

```
public partial class TAUX
{
    // the first 3 attributes are my primary key
    public short CAT_ID { get; set; } // foreign key
    public int C_GARANT { get; set; } // foreign key 
    public int TAUX_ID { get; set; }  

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Taux est obligatoire")]
    public decimal POURC_TAUX { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DATE_EFFET { get; set; }


    public virtual CATEGORIE CATEGORIE { get; set; }
    public virtual GARANTIE GARANTIE { get; set; }
}
```

And this the Error I get :

> system.ArgumentException: The number of primary key values passed must
>   match number of primary key values defined on the entity.

So I tried to do this :

```
public ActionResult Edit(int taux_id ,int c_garant, short cat_id)
{
TAUX taux = db.TAUX.Find(taux_id, c_garant, cat_id); 
... }
//////////
@Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", new {  id=d.TAUX_ID, c_garant=d.C_GARANT, cat_id=d.CAT_ID })
```

but I got this problem :

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'taux_id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32, Int32, Int16)' in
>   'pfebs0.Controllers.TauxController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter.

How to fix it (Same issue for deleteAction)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your problem. The three properties are your keys but not your primary keys as I saw in your code you just added comments to precise that the `CAT_ID` and `C_GARANT` are your foreign keys.
Regarding the first try. Meaning only `Taux_ID` is your Primary Key.
If you want the extension method `Find` work you need to precise the attribute `Key` above the property which is in your table is the primary key.
In your case you could have:

### Edit

```
  public partial class TAUX
 {
    public int TAUX_ID { get; set; }  

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Taux est obligatoire")]
    public decimal POURC_TAUX { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DATE_EFFET { get; set; }

    public short CAT_ID { get; set; } // foreign key
    public virtual CATEGORIE CATEGORIE { get; set; }
    public int C_GARANT { get; set; } // foreign key 
    public virtual GARANTIE GARANTIE { get; set; }
   }
```

Then in your Action, don't change:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id=0, int cat_Id =0,short c_garant=0)
   {
    TAUX taux = db.TAUX.Where(p=>p.TAUX_Id==id &&p.CAT_ID==cat_Id && p.C_GARANT==c_garant).FirstOrDefault();
    if (taux == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.CAT_ID = new SelectList(db.CATEGORIE, "CAT_ID", "LIBELLE", taux.CAT_ID);
    ViewBag.C_GARANT = new SelectList(db.GARANTIE, "C_GARANT", "LIB_ABREGE", taux.C_GARANT);
    return PartialView("_Edit",taux);
    }
```

Comment: Adding `[Key]` doesn't slove my problem because I'm using EF dataBase First and in my Oracle dataBase My primary key is set as `Taux_ID, Cat_ID and c_Garant`. And I get the same error `The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity`

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, see my Edit. Hope it will help.

Comment: i got this error `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object[]' because it is not a delegate type` at this part of code `(p=>p.TAUX_Id==id &&p.CAT_ID==cat_Id && p.C_GARANT==c_garant);`

Comment: You can use Where as it can also do the same job. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I changed my primary key to `Taux_id` only to slove this problem thank's any way :D

Answer (score 1):

Simplest thing to try is to change

```
public ActionResult Edit(int taux_id ,int c_garant, short cat_id)
```

into

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id ,int c_garant, short cat_id)
```

and leave

```
@Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", new {  id=d.TAUX_ID, c_garant=d.C_GARANT, cat_id=d.CAT_ID })
```

as is now

Comment: This dons't work same issue , the seconde error I get, To slove the problem I changed the primary key to `taux_ID` only

Comment: that makes me sad, you had to change design to accommodate for shortcoming of framework :(

Answer (score 0):

The Route values you pass in the `ActionLink` need to match the name of the parameters in the action method.

Change your `ActionLink` to this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", new { taux_id=d.TAUX_ID, c_garant=d.C_GARANT, cat_id=d.CAT_ID })
```

Comment: using `taux_id=d.taux_id` instead of `id=d.taux_id` rederict me to wrong page the link is like this `http://localhost:2698/taux/Edit?taux_id=21&c_garant=1300&cat_id=2`